# An ad-free Sudoku app on Android which allows customized board

Tags: android, game

I'm looking for Sudoku app on Android with the following **required** features:

- Free of charge
- Ad-free
- Let user input their own board and play
- Let user mark cell with possible candidates

It would also be good if the app has the following features, but these are **optional**:

- Automatically mark cell with possible candidates
- Automated solver

[This online solver](http://www.sudokuhints.com/free-sudoku.html) would be a good example of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THE free *(as in free speech and not just in free beer)* sudoku app that comes in my mind is [OpenSudoku](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=cz.romario.opensudoku):

- It is free in both ways
- For sure also ad-free
- Several input methods
- You can input possible candidates
- Auto-fill all possible candidates
- You can create your own boards
- You can import/export complete folders of boards ([some additional](https://code.google.com/archive/p/opensudoku-android/wikis/Puzzles.wiki) and [further nearly 15000(!)](http://opensudoku.p43.eu/) boards)
- Save current state (if you have to trial and error)